# Do batteries in series equalize charge

Tags: batteries, series, charge

If I connect 8 batteries in series and two of the batteries are fully charged, while the others are partially charged, do the batteries eventually reach some sort of equilibrium?

Comment: Nope. You get a misbalanced battery pack.

Comment: No.  The fully-charged cells will be overcharged when the charger tries to fully charge the other cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not generally a good idea, but it depends on the battery type.

NiCd is very tolerant of overcharging, and will equalise ok if you keep the current below C/10.

Other technologies will not work. Lithium batteries even have separate 'equalising wires" connected to each cell, so the charger can adjust the current individually.

Worse than charging an unbalanced pack is *discharging* it. The empty cells will be forcibly drained far past their safe minimum voltage, possibly until they are inverted. This will cause permanent damage, even if done at low current.

Answer (score 1):

No, a single series string will not equalise the cells in the normal course of charge/discharge, although the degree to which this is a problem and the degree to which it can be dealt with varies by battery chemistry - from not at all, to a reasonable amount.

Installing unequally charged cells in a series string is just plain bad practise - you'll hit over- or under-voltage limits on the over-/under-charged cells way before the others do, and you'll likely damage them.

Multiple single cells can be parallel connected, and they will equalise in voltage, although the current that can flow when they're initially parallel connected can be extreme, and may need to be mitigated with series resistors (and if you're talking about big batteries, then you're talking about beefy big resistors).

Multiple strings of series-connected cells that are connected in parallel will equalise with their peers on the overall series-string length (i.e. String-cells-1+2+3 in parallel with String-cells-4+5+6 will eventually equalise to the same voltage), BUT within the series string the cells will not equalise to each other by themselves, and you have the same original problem that some cells will reach full when charging, or flat when discharging, before their peers within the series string, and thus be damaged.

What's more, due to manufacturing & chemical & temperature variations between one cell to another, you can't expect all the cells in a string to stay at the same state-of-charge / voltage after multiple charge/discharge cycles.  That's when cell equalisation becomes a necessity.

Without knowing anything more specific about the chemistry & size of the cells you're referring to, that's about all that can be said.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to not do this because the charged cells will get stressed out while the flat ones are being brought up. From a theory viewpoint charging the cells independently is always best. If you must do this, keep currents very low and don't even think about lithium.