# Which better charge method for 12v 10w solar panel to 2x 6v 4.5ah battery?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, charging, 12v, series

i have 12v 10w solar panel and 2 x 6v/4.5ah battery. Im planning to build control that charge 12v battery (in this i series 2x6v battery) and after i read this [Do batteries in series equalize charge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173491/do-batteries-in-series-equalize-charge) said that itsn't a good idea to charge battery in series.. So, what should i do to charge 2x6v battery with 12v solar panel?

*Im using a lead acid battery

Answer (score 1):

Always remember we need 10% of current in ref. to capacity of battery to charge battery in good condition.

e.g for 4.5Ah battery we need to give min. 0.45A current to get it charge

You can have a parallel connection of both battery to get charging done. There are ample of design and circuit on google that can help you out for connection.

Comment: what happen if i connect it to series for charge? since i use the battery in series for 12v